# android studio 3 build unable to merge dex

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

Hello suddenly my android project shows this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Before some days everything worked fine and I just opened it again after some days and shows me this
I have tried all the possible solutions I found here but nothing worked can you help me on this?

Here is my byuild.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fire.stmtfadmin"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}






dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-multiple-viewtypes-adapter:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.StevenDXC:DxLoadingButton:2.0'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk:android-morphing-button:98a4986e56' // commit hash
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.12.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? Enable multidex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999540/unable-to-merge-dex-android-studio-error/48999593#48999593

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: yeah i tried this too but i had the same error

Comment: Try to put multiDexEnabled true to defaultConfig and both release and debug buildTypes

Answer (score 0):

To use the **11.4.0** version of Firebase, you need to add `maven url` to your `build.gradle` file like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're using the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

where it means you want to use the latest version. The latest version 27.1.0.

Try using:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

And never use `+` for your dependency version. So you can reproduce and debug the same build if there is any problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your replies but the only solution that worked for me was to add this line to build.gradle(Module:app):

```
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0'
```

i hope this will help the others